# FT5x06 Calibration procedure

Tags: driver, windows-ce, touchscreen, calibration

I have successfully integrated a driver for an FTX506 touch screen on Windows CE 7. This driver has been in use for almost a year on 2 prototypes. Lately, on one of them, the touch events stopped working on the upper side of the screen. The dead zone is a perfect rectangle that represents 10% of the screen height, from the top.

I am wondering if this can be resolved with a calibration but I can't find the calibration procedure for this chip. All I found so far is the calibration routine in linux sources:

```
int fts_ctpm_auto_clb(struct i2c_client *client)
{
    unsigned char uc_temp;
    unsigned char i ;

    printk("[FTS] start auto CLB.\n");
    msleep(200);
    ft5x0x_write_reg(client,0, 0x40);  
    delay_qt_ms(100);   //make sure already enter factory mode
    ft5x0x_write_reg(client,2, 0x4);  //write command to start calibration
    delay_qt_ms(300);
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        ft5x06_get_reg(client,0,&uc_temp);
        if ( ((uc_temp&0x70)>>4) == 0x0)  //return to normal mode, calibration finish
        {
            break;
        }
        delay_qt_ms(200);
        printk("[FTS] waiting calibration %d\n",i);

    }
    printk("[FTS] calibration OK.\n");

    msleep(300);
    ft5x0x_write_reg(client,0, 0x40);  //goto factory mode
    delay_qt_ms(100);   //make sure already enter factory mode
    ft5x0x_write_reg(client,2, 0x5);  //store CLB result
    delay_qt_ms(300);
    ft5x0x_write_reg(client,0, 0x0); //return to normal mode 
    msleep(300);
    printk("[FTS] store CLB result OK.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I cross this code with the FT5X06 registers, it's a bit confusing.

For instance:

- Write (0, 0x40) --> *Enter factory mode* : There is no factory mode in
  the manual
- Write (2,0x4) --> *Start calibration* : 0x02 is the "Touch
  Points" register, does not start a calibration

Plus, there is an auto-calib register on the chip (ID_G_AUTO_CLB_MODE). Writing it to 0x00 has no effect (at least not in my case) and we always read 0xFF.

If someone can point me to the right direction to perform the calibration of the screen, that would be great.

Some additional info:

- I checked the interrupt signal of the chip : no interrupt when a touch happens in the dead zone
- I tried to read touch register values while pressing the screen: no touch detected in the dead zone.

Documents I am using:
https://media.digikey.com/pdf/PCNs/NewHaven%20Display/ECN_12-12-14.pdf